# Continuously add multiple data to my excel database but in the same column only

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Here is my code below:**

```
       *Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
       Dim iRow As Long
       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
       Dim rngNullString
 'find first empty row in database

Set rngNullString = Intersect(ws.Columns("B"), ws.Columns("B")).Find("")
    If rngNullString.Row < ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row Then
        Set rngNullString = Intersect(ws.Columns("B"), ws.Columns("B")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    End If
iRow = rngNullString.Row


      ' iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      ' SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
      'check for Name number
      If Trim(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = "" Then
      Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please complete the FORM"
      Exit Sub
      End If

      'copy the data to the database
      ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox21.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox39.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox112.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox22.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox40.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox11.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox15.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox113.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox23.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox41.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox17.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox21.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox114.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox24.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox42.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox23.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox27.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox115.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox25.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox43.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox29.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox33.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox116.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox26.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox44.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox35.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox39.Value
      ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox117.Value
      MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
      'clear the data
       End Sub*
```

**My code is not working, only 1 row is able to add. The data's are in the same columns but different rows. As you can see below (attached photo), if I will add a value on my combobox and textbox I want to add multiple data's in the rows respectively.

Comment: your code overwrite the same row 6 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will clear your sheet column(c).

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()


    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
    Dim rngNullString
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim vDB() As Variant
       
 'find first empty row in database
        
    Set Target = ws.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)

      'check for Name number
      If Trim(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = "" Then
            Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
            MsgBox "Please complete the FORM"
            Exit Sub
      End If

    'copy the data to the database
    ReDim vDB(1 To 6, 1 To 6) 'set the array size
    
    vDB(1, 1) = Me.ComboBox21.Value
    vDB(1, 3) = Me.ComboBox39.Value
    vDB(1, 4) = Me.TextBox8.Value
    vDB(1, 5) = Me.TextBox9.Value
    vDB(1, 6) = Me.TextBox112.Value
    
    vDB(2, 1) = Me.ComboBox22.Value
    vDB(2, 3) = Me.ComboBox40.Value
    vDB(2, 4) = Me.TextBox11.Value
    vDB(2, 6) = Me.TextBox15.Value
    vDB(2, 6) = Me.TextBox113.Value
    
    vDB(3, 1) = Me.ComboBox23.Value
    vDB(3, 3) = Me.ComboBox41.Value
    vDB(3, 4) = Me.TextBox17.Value
    vDB(3, 5) = Me.TextBox21.Value
    vDB(3, 6) = Me.TextBox114.Value
    
    vDB(4, 1) = Me.ComboBox24.Value
    vDB(4, 3) = Me.ComboBox42.Value
    vDB(4, 4) = Me.TextBox23.Value
    vDB(4, 5) = Me.TextBox27.Value
    vDB(4, 6) = Me.TextBox115.Value
    
    vDB(5, 1) = Me.ComboBox25.Value
    vDB(5, 3) = Me.ComboBox43.Value
    vDB(5, 4) = Me.TextBox29.Value
    vDB(5, 5) = Me.TextBox33.Value
    vDB(5, 6) = Me.TextBox116.Value
    
    vDB(6, 1) = Me.ComboBox26.Value
    vDB(6, 3) = Me.ComboBox44.Value
    vDB(6, 4) = Me.TextBox35.Value
    vDB(6, 5) = Me.TextBox39.Value
    vDB(6, 6) = Me.TextBox117.Value
    
    Target.Resize(6, 6) = vDB
    MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
      'clear the data
End Sub
```